# confusing issues with the any type in Nim

Tags: generics, nim-lang

I have a type:

```
type
  generic_seq[T] = ref object
    data: T
    case base: bool
    of false: down: generic_seq[any]
    of true: discard
```

and the following line of code:

```
var current_args: generic_seq[int] = generic_seq[int](base: true.bool, data: 3)
```

and the compiler line: `nim c -r main` gives the error: `Error: invalid type: 'auto' in this context: 'generic_seq[system.int]' for var`

However I fail to see where the any type would be causing a type confusion problem. The generic_seq object is already a hackier "safer" version of the original:

```
type
  generic_seq[T] = ref object
    data: T
    down: generic_seq[any]
```

which also failed when passed arguments `generic_seq[int](data: 3, down: nil)` in the same way. I don't see where the nonconcrete type is exposed with any ambiguity. What am I missing? Could it be a bad compiler implementation?

Comment: Hey, this might be somewhat relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67958826/4039050

Answer (score 2):

I think your confusion arises from trying to do this with generics. What you are trying to do is to, if I'm getting this right, is to declare a singly linked list of objects, which can be of any type. Moreover, you don't want to declare this type at compile time. This means you'll have to do it using RTTI, using Nim's typeinfo module. Note that the typeinfo module is not advised as it has a lot of gotchas, namely regarding the lifetime of objects.

Here's a generic sequence using typeinfo:

```
import typeinfo

type
  genSeq = ref object
    data: Any
    down: genSeq

var intDatum = 3
var strDatum = "hello, world!"
let child = genSeq(data: strDatum.toAny, down:nil)
let a = genSeq(data: intDatum.toAny, down: child)
echo a.data.getInt    # echos 3
echo a.down.data.getString # echos "hello, world!"
```

However, this may not be what you want, since RTTI is generally expensive. If the set of objects you want to use is limited, you can use case expressions to get the same result without the limitations of RTTI.

For future questions, you can also cross-post to the nim forum: [forum.nim-lang.org](https://forum.nim-lang.org) for a faster reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
type
  Base=ref object of RootObj
  Generic[T]=ref object of Base
    data:T
var s:seq[Base]= @[]
s.add(Generic[int](data:3))
s.add(Generic[float](data:3.1))
echo(len(s))
```

Perhaps this is what you want based on the topic https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/1160