# Trouble defining a Nim concept with an auto type inside

Tags: generics, types, typeclass, nim-lang, concept

I'm having trouble defining a concept with an `auto` type inside.
It looks like Nim is complaining that `type T = auto` becomes `untyped`.

Here is a minimal example ([run it online here](https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=3pK8)) taken basically from [from the docs](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual_experimental.html#concepts-generic-concepts-and-type-binding-rules)):

```py
import sugar, typetraits

type
  Functor[A] {.explain.} = concept f
    type MatchedGenericType = genericHead(typeof(f))
      # `f` will be a value of a type such as `Option[T]`
      # `MatchedGenericType` will become the `Option` type
    
    # f.val is A
      # The Functor should provide a way to obtain
      # a value stored inside it
    
    type T = auto
    map(f, A -> T) is MatchedGenericType[T]
      # And it should provide a way to map one instance of
      # the Functor to an instance of a different type, given
      # a suitable `map` operation for the enclosed values

import options
echo Option[int] is Functor # should print true but doesn't!

# The above came straight from
# <https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual_experimental.html#concepts-generic-concepts-and-type-binding-rules>
  

proc f(x: Functor) = echo "yes!"
f(some(1))
```

Here's the relevant part of the error (**beside the fact that the docs say `Option[int] is Functor` should be `true` but isn't**):

```
proc map[T, R](self: Option[T]; callback: proc (input: T): R): Option[R]
  first type mismatch at position: 2
  required type for callback: proc (input: T): R{.closure.}
  but expression 'proc (i0: A): T' is of type: type proc (i0: int): untyped{.closure.}
```

I'm basically *copy-pasting from the docs* here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: looks as though this example hasn't ever worked properly https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/5650

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to answer your question about using `auto` inside a concept body, my gut is that is rather unlikely to work.

I can get your example to work by removing the auto stuff and whatever's going on with calling `map` with a typedef parameter?  I don't understand that either.

```
import sugar, typetraits

type
  Functor[A] {.explain.} = concept f,type t
    type MatchedGenericType = genericHead(typeof(f))
      # `f` will be a value of a type such as `Option[T]`
      # `MatchedGenericType` will become the `Option` type
    
    # f.val is A
      # The Functor should provide a way to obtain
      # a value stored inside it
    
    #type T = auto
    proc mapto[T](x:t):MatchedGenericType[T] = map(f,default(A->T))
    #map(f, A->T) is MatchedGenericType[T]
      # And it should provide a way to map one instance of
      # the Functor to a instance of a different type, given
      # a suitable `map` operation for the enclosed values

import options
echo Option[int] is Functor # prints true

# The above came straight from <https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual_experimental.html#concepts-generic-concepts-and-type-binding-rules>.
  
proc f(x: Functor) = echo "yes!"
f(some(1))
```

Comment: Hey, thank you ! Very interesting, and the problem seems indeed to be the `auto` keyword. I took the freedom to [post your example in the mentioned issue](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/5650#issuecomment-860227825). I also link the [playground](https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=3pPI).